# If Possession is played while executing another Possession, who takes the next turn?

Tags: dominion, dominion-alchemy

In Dominion: Alchemy, you can play Possession to "possess" the player to your left and effectively take over his next turn.  What happens if he has a Possession in his hand, and you play it during that possessed turn?

#### Example

(Turn order is Alex, then Bob, then Carl)

Alex plays Possession.
He controls Bob's next turn, and plays a Possession from Bob's hand.
This means someone will possess Carl on the next turn - but is it Bob, or Alex?

Comment: I have a problem with the card possesion. The text reads: "The player on your left takes and extra turn...". This is my problem. A player can not take an "EXTRA TURN" if they have not yet HAD their turn. My interpretation (which I have been told is incorrect) is that when possession is played, you finish YOUR turn, the next player takes THEIR turn, and then that player has to take an EXTRA TURN which you get to control. If the card had said "You take an extra turn and control what the player on your left does", then that would be one thing. But it does NOT say that.

Comment: @Markem -- I've migrated your answer to a comment, as it doesn't answer the question asked.  I also apologize as your answer was cut off due to the size restrictions of comments.  If you want, you can reformat your answer as a separate question, as it seemed interesting; just make sure you phrase it as a question.

Comment: "Extra turn" in this context just means a turn that's not part of the standard rotation.  "Extra" doesn't need to imply ordering or timing, just that it's additional.  That said, the exact phrasing on Possession comes from a lot of playtesting trying to land the least confusing, most-consistent-with-other-cards way to phrase it. For example, many cards refer to "you" which would be confusing if Alex was taking the extra turn, but using Bob's hand as you suggest.  Having it be Bob's turn, but giving Alex the decision-making power, simplifies interactions with all the other cards.

Comment: **POSSESSION-CEPTION**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If Bob plays Possession, even if he is currently being possessed by Alex, Bob will control Carl's next turn.

This basically means if you are possessing someone, you should *not* have them play Possession.  Especially in a 2 player game.

(Note that sometimess you can't avoid playing a Possession - for example if you play a Golem, you might end up being required to play Possession as well.)

Answer (score 12):

During a Possession turn, it is still Bob's turn - only three things are different than a normal turn:

1. Alex makes all decisions for Bob
2. Alex gains all cards Bob would normally gain
3. Any cards trashed are discarded instead

Any card text that says "you" still refers to Bob, regardless of the fact that Alex is making the decisions.

So playing a Possession will cause Bob to possess Carl next turn.

Answer (score 9):

> If you make someone play Possession
>   during a turn in which you Possessed
>   them, that will make that player
>   Possess the player to his left, rather
>   than you getting to Possess anyone
>   further.

Dominion: Alchemy Official Rules,  Kingdom Card Descriptions booklet, page 3.

(In other words, this one is literally in the rulebook)

And before you ask, this affects Outpost the same way; the deck owner plays the Outpost hand, I just didn't quote that part.