# If an Outpost is played during a Possessed hand, is the Outpost hand played next?

Tags: dominion, dominion-alchemy, dominion-seaside

As pointed out in a [previous question's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/10/if-possession-is-played-while-executing-another-possession-who-takes-the-next-tu/18#18), you may be forced to play an Outpost or Possession while you are possessing someone else's hand, despite the deck's owner getting to play the Outpost/Possession hand and not you.

However, Outpost creates an ambiguity.  Outpost's rules say to play another hand immediately after this one.  However, due to the Possession, the player's normal turn has not yet taken place.

Does the player take their normal turn next or the Outpost turn next?

Comment: Side note: My opinion is that they'd play the Outpost turn first, then their normal turn.

Comment: Just be careful if you are Possessing someone and you have them play an Outpost, then a Possession, then another Outpost. You're in for a wild ride.

Comment: @Mag Roader: You can't play multiple Outposts in the same turn, nor do you get to play any hand beyond the first Possession hand, as [previously discussed](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/10/if-possession-is-played-while-executing-another-possession-who-takes-the-next-tu/729#729).

Comment: I guess the wild ride would be for the one who got possessed in the first place. Outpost twice in the same turn is possible (like via Golem), it just doesn't *help* you normally. But now I'm curious what happens if you do play Outpost Possession Outpost. Meh, this isn't a conversation for comments.

Comment: @Mag Roader: "If you manage to play Outpost twice in one turn, you will still get only one extra turn.  If you play Outpost during an extra turn, it won't give you another turn." Official Dominion Seaside rules, Kingdom Card Descriptions booklet, page 3.  Now, this wording sounds like it would affect Possession's extra turn, but Alchemy's rules clarify that... specifically, the turn after the Possessed turn is the player's normal turn, not an extra turn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The turn Outpost is referring to is "this one", the Possession turn.  Outpost doesn't really care what turn it was played on.

So during the clean-up phase of the Possession turn, the possessed player will draw 3 cards instead of 5, and immediately take their Outpost turn.

At the end of the Outpost turn, the originally possessed player will draw 5 cards as normal.  Turn order then returns to where we were before the Possession was played, so it's now the possessed player's turn (finally!) and they take a normal turn.

So your opinion is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Outpost card has the text "This can't cause you to take more than two consecutive turns" on it. I thought this would mean that the player who had been possessed would not take another turn after the outpost turn, but apparently (according to isotropic) it does not, even though that player takes three consecutive turns, one when he is possessed, one from the Outpost and one normal one.

Comment: I think the intention is "This special Outpost 3-card turn can't be the 3rd consecutively" - it's not asking you to predict whether, after this card's effects happen, some OTHER mechanic (normal turn order) will create a 3rd turn in a row.  Just this card can't create a 3rd turn in a row.

Comment: The reason for this is that Alchemy's rules for Possession override Seaside's rules for Outpost: "If you make someone play an Outpost during a turn in which you Possessed them, that player will get the extra turn and make decisions during it and so forth, not you;"